# What is the form of Srikalika?

Tags: puranas, tantra, kali

According to the chapter three of the Todalatantra, the eight forms of Devi Kalika are 1. Dakshinakali, 2. Siddhakali, 3.Guhyakali, 4.Srikali, 5.Bhadrakali, 6.Chamundakali, 7. Smashankali and 8.Mahakali.

The descriptions of all but Srikali is available. Can anyone provide the details of Srikali?

Comment: So you want a Dhyana Sloka for that form?

Comment: @Rickross yes..